# Django list of files return an empty array

Tags: python, django

I'm starting with Django, so I'm pretty new to this. I'm sending a file to the Django server, saving it, trying to get the last file (the one I just send) from the saved folder and then I want to perform some processes on that file, after that I want to delete the original file. I already managed to upload and save the file to the filesystem, but I'm having trouble selecting this file from the folder.

I'm trying select and remove it this way:

```
@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
def geojson_to_shape_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            # serializer.save() calls .create() in serializers.py
            file = serializer.save()

            # Get last saved file
            print("Analyzing last posted file...")
            list_of_files = glob.glob('../media/temp_files/*')
            print(list_of_files)
            if list_of_files:
                latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
                print("Deleting last posted file...")
                try:
                    os.remove(latest_file)
                    pass
                except:
                    print("Can't remove the file")

            return Response(FileSerializer(file).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And this code returns:

```
Analyzing last posted file...
[]
```

I tried to run a script in the same folder with these file interactions and it run with no problems, so I thinking is some django permission issue. I also tried to change the path to `settings.MEDIA_ROOT + 'temp_files/*'`, but the problem persists.

Comment: Figure out the absolute path of the directory, don't rely on a hard-coded relative `../media`.

Comment: Okay, that was it, I feel pretty dumb for not trying this earlier. But it isn't possible to work with relative paths?

Comment: By the way, this approach can also suffer from a race condition, if two requests manage to upload a file at approximately the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will fix this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentionned by AKX, your issue is here:

```
list_of_files = glob.glob('../media/temp_files/*')
```

Relative path are resolved against the current working directory, which can actually be just anything, so you need to use absolute path if you expect your code to work reliably.

> But it isn't possible to work with relative paths?

Well, technically yes, but as I stated above - and as you already found out by yourself -, the final result is totally unpredictable. And no, changing the current working directory is not a solution - it's unreliable too (some other code - possibly in another thread - can change it back under your feet), and since it requires knowing the absolute path to switch to, it's much simpler to just build a proper absolute path.

NB: you may want to have a look at `os.path` and (python3.x) the `path` module for filesystem path manipulations.

Comment: Very understandable, thank you for the information. Since my folder structure will not change I defined a variable with the current path: `current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)`. Then, in the list_of_files variable: `glob.glob(current_path + '/../media/temp_files/*')`. I don't know if it could generate any future problems, but it's working.

Comment: Well, hardcoding path separators could theoretically be an issue (that's why we have `os.path` and the `Path` modules as abstraction layers). Also, "working" files (files created / written / deleted by the program) should live outside your source code directory, and where they live should preferably be configurable  - that's why Django has the `MEDIA_ROOT` setting for users uploaded files.

Comment: Okay, did some tests and was able to use the `MEDIA_ROOT` setting. Using now `media_root_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT ` and `list_of_files = glob.glob(media_root_path + '/temp_files/*')`. As suggested, I will also change the path of `MEDIA_ROOT` to outside the source code directory. Once again, thank you for all clarification.

Comment: Just beware that `MEDIA_ROOT` is primarily intended for files that are to be publicly served by the frontend server - so if you want to keep those files private, you may want to define a distinct custom setting.